# if i add an extension to the hub site, will it effect all associated sites?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-extensions, hub-site

i have an extension to handle analytics in a site, if i make the site as hub site and add few other site as associated site, will it be able to get that extension in all over the associated sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you deploy your SPFX extension only to a site scope instead of deploying it to the tenant via app catalog site? As per my test, the associated sites will not be able to get that extension.

Comment: thank you. you are right. the extension  won't work for the associated sites